# How to secure connection string in vb.net 2008?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am developing an application connected to a database, I'm using visual studio 2008 (visual basic) for my front end and mysql for my back-end. When creating a connection string, vb.net prompts me with a warning saying that the connection string that I am creating contains a sensitive data and it would be too risky to include that data in the connection string... I could just ignore it's warning and my application would work fine but I'm concerned about the security of my data, can someone help me pls?...

I already read some in the internet about securing connection strings but I can't seem to grasp the idea on to implement it and not sure if it really is the solution I am looking for...

Comment: "I can't seem to grasp the idea on to implement it" - What have you read and what don't you understand?

Comment: Im sorry I was talking about how to implement security on connection strings..i found one in the internet and it says something about regiis tool, but I don't know if I can also use it in my application..

Comment: Difficult to know what you mean without a _link_ to the article. As for using it - did you try?

Comment: I think I just need to read some more I guess..thanks for your time anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example shows how to encrypt the connectionStrings section of the Web.config file for an application named SampleApplication:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

For non-IIS apps, use Protected Configuration

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: thank you ^_^ I think I need to read some more about securing connection string first. I'll also try your advise while reading.